# How to configure an Airport Express router to block a machine after many failed wifi connection attempts?

Tags: security, airport

There's someone in my neighbourhood that keeps cracking the WPA2 password on my Airport Extreme router, connecting, and using between 5 to 15 Gigs of bandwidth a day.

I've read online that with utilities, even a complex WPA2 password can be cracked within hours or a couple of days.

Is there a way to configure my Airport Extreme router to block connection attempts from a machine after X number of failed password attempts?

Comment: I assume your passwords are better than "Password1234" or similar. MAC based blocking is possible but MACs can be spoofed as well (with some effort). For an attacker willing (and able) to crack WPA2 keys this will probably not impose a big hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do that, but you can use the "timed access" feature to block all MAC addresses other than the ones you own.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=508984

Answer (score 0):

He isn't cracking your WPA2 password.  Nearly impossible if you have a decent password.  He has your machine root'd (rootkit) and he is simply grabbing your passwords out of keychain.  Change all passwords and download little snitch.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what all passwords means? Bank passwords, web passwords, or just Mac passwords and router passwords? Also, how does little snitch fit into this question/answer.